# Randomly permute $\{1,\cdots,100\}$. What is the probability that none of the $S_k$'s defined by $\sigma(1)+\cdots+\sigma(k)$ is divisible by $3$?

Tags: probability, proof-verification, stochastic-processes, permutations, contest-math

> After randomly permuting the numbers from $1$ to $100$, what is the
>   probability that none of the $S_k$'s defined by 
>   $S_k =\sigma(1)+\cdots+\sigma(k)$ is divisible by $3$?

I think I have a solution. Here is my proposed solution:

Consider all the numbers from $1$ to $100$ modulo $3$. We have $33$ zeroes, $34$ ones and $33$ twos. Now let's see which permutations are eligible:

First of all, it does not matter where those numbers divisible by $3$ are placed after permutation because they are zero modulo $3$. I claim there exists only one possible pattern:

$$1 \hspace{5px} \underbrace{1\hspace{5px} 2\hspace{5px} 1\hspace{5px} 2\hspace{5px} 1\hspace{5px} 2\hspace{5px} 1\hspace{5px} \cdots \hspace{5px} 1 \hspace{5px}2}_{\text{33 times}}$$

where the remaining zeroes can be put anywhere. Why is this the only pattern? Well, notice that after we have chosen $\sigma(1)$, no two consecutive sigmas can be $1$ modulo $3$. Because if $S_k\equiv x \pmod{3}$, then $S_{k+1} \equiv x+1 \pmod{3}$ and $S_{k+2} \equiv x+2 \pmod{3}$. One of these three must be divisible by $3$. Hence, no consecutive $1$'s can be in the list after the first entry.

The same argument applies to any two consecutive sigmas that are equal to $2$ modulo $3$. So, after we have chosen $\sigma(1)$, the rest of the list should be filled with alternating $1$'s and $2$'s with $0$'s placed arbitrarily. So, we get two options:

$$\text{Pattern I: } \hspace{5px} 1 \hspace{5px}1\hspace{5px} 2\hspace{5px} 1\hspace{5px} 2\hspace{5px} 1\hspace{5px} 2\hspace{5px} 1\hspace{5px} \cdots$$
$$\text{Pattern II: } \hspace{5px} 2 \hspace{5px}2\hspace{5px} 1\hspace{5px} 2\hspace{5px} 1\hspace{5px} 2\hspace{5px} 1\hspace{5px} 2\hspace{5px} \cdots$$

The second pattern is impossible. Because the numbers of $1$'s and $2$'s are limited and we cannot fit $34$ ones and $33$ twos in the second pattern.

Hence, we only need to count the number of ways we can place zeroes in the only remaining pattern (pattern I) to find out the probability. The final answer therefore is equal to:

$$\frac{{67+33-1}\choose{33}}{{100 \choose 33} \times {67 \choose 34}}=\frac{{99}\choose{33}}{{100 \choose 33} \times {67 \choose 34}} \approx 4.7\times 10^{-20}$$

So, the answer is extremely small and the probability is almost $0$.

Comment: Don't you have to take the various sequences of the ones and twos into account? I mean 4, 7, 5, 10, ... is a different sequence as 7, 10, 5, 4, ... but mod 3 both show the pattern 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, ...; The first number can't be a zero mod 3, but the rest of the 99 places can be filled with the 33 zeroes. So I end up with $33! * 33! * 34! * {{99}\choose{33}} / 100!$ That's a bit larger than your result. (33! sequences of zeroes, 33! sequences of twos, 34! sequences of ones and 33 out of 99 to place the zeroes). I'm not an expert on counting though

Comment: @Ronald  Well, the correct result, as you and leonboy stated, is about $4.71\times 10^{-20}$.  I wouldn't say it is *a bit larger* than the OP's answer.  :D

Comment: @Ronald  I read your comment again. I think you're right. :D That's also a beautiful way to count it and it can be written as an answer, I think. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis is correct so far. So I can concentrate on the counting.

Obviously a sequence can't start with a number that is zero mod 3. This means that the zeroes can be placed somewhere on the remaining 99 places. This gives ${99}\choose{33}$ possibilities. The sequence of zeroes are 33 different values. Hence there are $33!$ different sequences.

The pattern of the ones and twos has been proven to be $1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, ...$
There are 34 ones that can be ordered in $34!$ ways. And for the twos we have $33!$ different sequences.

This means we have $33! * 34! * 33! * {{99}\choose{33}}$ valid sequences.
In total there are $100!$ possible sequences. The probability to hit one of the desired ones is thus

$$
\frac{33! * 34! * 33! * {{99}\choose{33}}}{100!}
$$

Wolfram tells me this is $\frac{1}{21233613041224311000} \approx 4.71 \times 10^{-20}$

Answer (score 3):

The reasoning looks correct.

But the counting of ways seems wrong. The $3^{100}$ denominator makes no sense to me. It should rather be  the [multinomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalization_to_multinomials) $ \binom{100}{33, 34,33}$. Also, the numerator should be $\binom{99}{66}=\binom{99}{33}$

Comment: The denominator has to be equal to ${100 \choose{33}} \times {67 \choose {34}}$. Do you agree?

Comment: @stressedout I agree

Comment: "We can place them in 34 locations" Why? The $1/2$ elements are 67. More simply: given that the $1/2$'s sequence (length $67$) is fixed, it only remains to determine its location inside the full sequence (length $100$). Hence we have $\binom{100}{67}=\binom{100}{33}$ ways.

Comment: Taking into account that a $0$ cannot be placed at the beginning (you're right!), then the first place is fixed, we need to place the remaining 66 elements inside the 99 places, then the count is $\binom{99}{66}=\binom{99}{33}$. Fixed.

Comment: I deleted my previous comments for the discussion not to get too long. In other words, we have $67$ locations because we can place the $33$ zeroes between $1$'s and $2$'s or at the end of the string. Also, the first location is not eligible because then $S_1$ would be divisible by $3$. The ways of doing this is equal to the number of solutions to $x_1+\cdots+x_{67}=33$. So, it is equal to ${{67+33-1}\choose{33}} = {{99} \choose{33}} = {{99} \choose{66}}$. Do you agree?

Comment: Thank you for your help, Leonbloy. You corrected two of my mistakes. I appreciate it.